# Hibernate could not resolve property error

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I am currently getting absolutely bally nowhere with a problem with Hibernate where I am given the message:

```
Your page request has caused a QueryException: could not resolve property: PERSON_ID of: library.model.Person [FROM library.model.Person p JOIN Book b ON p.PERSON_ID = b.PERSON_ID WHERE p.PERSON_ID = 2] error:
```

In the method below:

```
@Override
public Person getPersonAndBooks(Integer personId) {
    logger.info(PersonDAOImpl.class.getName() + ".listBooksForPerson() method called.");

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();                  
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Person p JOIN Book b ON p.PERSON_ID = b.PERSON_ID WHERE p.PERSON_ID = " + personId);                
    List<Person> persons = query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Person.class)).list();
    List<Book> books = persons.get(0).getBooks();
        for (Book b : books) {
           System.out.println("Here " + b.toString());
        }    
        return persons.get(0);  
    }        
    finally {
        session.close();
    }         
}
```

But I see nothing wrong in the SQL and it works perfectly well in Apache Derby.

I've tried a number of things on StackOverflow and elsewhere but nothing resolves the issue.

There are two classes in a simple application:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

// Attributes.    
@Id
@Column(name="PERSON_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)    
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer personId;

@Column(name="NAME", nullable=false, length=50)      
private String name;

@Column(name="ADDRESS", nullable=false, length=100)
private String address;

@Column(name="TELEPHONE", nullable=false, length=10)
private String telephone;

@Column(name="EMAIL", nullable=false, length=50)
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)     
private List<Book> books;
```

And Book:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book implements Serializable {

// Attributes.
@Id
@Column(name="BOOK_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer bookId;

@Column(name="AUTHOR", nullable=false, length=50)
private String author;

@Column(name="TITLE", nullable=false, length=50)
private String title;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION", nullable=false, length=500)
private String description;

@Column(name="ONLOAN", nullable=false, length=5)
private String onLoan;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")    
private Person person;
```

Each maps to database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
  PERSON_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),    
  NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
  ADDRESS VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  TELEPHONE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,      
  CONSTRAINT PRIMARY_KEY_PERSON PRIMARY KEY(PERSON_ID)
)
```

And Book is:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK (
  BOOK_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),    
  AUTHOR VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
  TITLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  ONLOAN VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  PERSON_ID INTEGER,   
  CONSTRAINT PRIMARY_KEY_BOOK PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN_KEY_BOOK FOREIGN KEY(PERSON_ID) REFERENCES PERSON(PERSON_ID)  
)
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

And if when the SQL finally works, if I am using the right method to convert the output into a Person object where a Person has an arraylist of Book?

My method to get a books for a Person is:

```
// Calls books.jsp for a Person.
@RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listBooks(@RequestParam("personId") String personId, 
                        Model model) {    
    logger.info(PersonController.class.getName() + ".listBooks() method called."); 


    Person person = personService.get(Integer.parseInt(personId));  
    List<Book> books = bookService.listBooksForPerson(Integer.parseInt(personId));                

    // Set view.
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    model.addAttribute("books", books);
    return "view/books";
}
```

Which does work.

Full stack trace follows:

> Your page request has caused a LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: library.model.Person.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session error:

```
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294)
library.controller.PersonController.getLogin(PersonController.java:104)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safer still than HQL is using the [criteria API](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listBooks(@RequestParam("personId") String personId, 
                        Model model) {    

    Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
    query.addRestriction("personId", personId);
    Person me = query.list().get(1);
    List<Book> myBooks = me.getBooks();
    model.setAttribute("person", me);
    model.setAttribute("books", myBooks);
    return "view/books";
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

// Attributes.    
@Id
@Column(name="PERSON_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)    
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer personId;

@Column(name="NAME", nullable=false, length=50)      
private String name;

@Column(name="ADDRESS", nullable=false, length=100)
private String address;

@Column(name="TELEPHONE", nullable=false, length=10)
private String telephone;

@Column(name="EMAIL", nullable=false, length=50)
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)     
private List<Book> books;
}
```

Comment: I've changed `setAttribute` to `addAttribute`. But where is `session` coming from: is it of type `HTTPSession`?

Comment: session's your hibernate session

Comment: Gives me: `Your page request has caused a LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: library.model.Person.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session error:`

Comment: Put a fetch type of EAGER?

Comment: I have tried that and it causes other problems. So at the moment, I am doing a separate get on the Book table.

Comment: `other problems`? Please elaborate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346757/what-is-the-correct-hibernate-query-syntax-for-a-join-between-two-classes-tabl

Comment: When you put FetchType.EAGER in your person's books, what error does it give?

Comment: If I dp this, the application won't compile.

Comment: Apart from the use of EAGER above, that's what I have. But running with EAGER causes runtime failure. Hibernate is trying to read a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: In your hibernate.cfg.xml, make sure your `hibernate.ddl-auto` property is set to `update`, `create` or `create-drop`

Comment: Yes, it is normally set to `validate`. The damnedest thing though is that `LAZY` seems to be working. I changed the Book class and removed the instance of Person from it.

Comment: No, it is set by **default** to `validate`, which, IMO, is braindead.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote your HQL query as if it was a SQL query. It's not. HQL and JPQL are different languages.

HQL never uses table and column names. It always uses entity names and their persistent field names (i.e. personId and not PERSON_ID) and their associations. Joins in HQL consists in navigating through association between entities. HQL queries thus don't have ON clauses.

A correct HQL query would be

```
 select p from Person p join p.books where p.id = :personId
```

Note that I use a named parameter in the query, that must be bound, instead of using concatenation which is the open door to SQL injection attacks (just as in SQL).

The above query would select the person identified by the given ID, unless it doesn't have any book. You don't need any result transformer to get the result of this query: it's a Person instance.

I strongly suggest you read [the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql), which explains HQL queries.

That said, you don't need any query to implement a method to get a person by ID. All you need is

```
Person p = (Person) session.get(Person.class, personId);
// now you can display the person and its books.
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion in code appended to the question but it does not return the books for the Person. –

Comment: It loads them lazily. You don't have to issue a second query to get the books of the person. Just call person.getBooks(). That's the whole point of using an ORM and having associations between entities. I repeat my suggestion: read the Hibernate documentation.

Comment: I call a method from a controller which performs `return (Person) session.get(Person.class, personId);` and assigns the result to a Person instance. But if I do call person.getBooks() after this, I get `Your page request has caused a LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: library.model.Person.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session error:`. 

This has bedevilled me today so I must conclude that something must be wrong with the relationship declarations in the two Java classes I have but I can't see what.

Comment: So read what a LazyInitializationException is in the documentation, and do what is required to avoid it, like simply calling `Hibernate.initialize(person.getBooks())` while still inside the transaction, or using an OpenSessionInView Spring interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly after you get Person from controller `return (Person) session.get(Person.class, personId);` This person instance is not having books as books are loaded by lazily. And when you call person.getBooks() it requires an open session to load the books but in your DAO session got already closed in finally block which internally causes `LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: library.model.Person.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session error:`

Try to load books EAGERLY.

Change your code

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)     
private List<Book> books;
```

Comment: Your explanation sounds correct. I have a page which checks for the Person's existence using the same `return (Person) session.get(Person.class, personId);` method as I do when I need to retrieve the Person's Books. But this time, Hibernate gives me a `Your page request has caused a SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement error:`. so I have switched back to LAZY.

Comment: do not switch back to LAZY and SQLGrammarException tells that something is wrong with your HQL or SQL

Comment: I can easily switch back to EAGER. But I want to use LAZY because that is the norm. I just don't know what is affecting the application.

Comment: if you use LAZY, you need to explicitly load all books of each Person before your session closes.

Comment: True, but this is only a simple demo application so the amount of data is miniscule. And if I have the foreign key constraints set correctly in both Java and SQL, I would have thought LAZY would work.

Comment: It's been appended to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In HQL no need to use ON condition in joins hibernate will generate this on runtime. And only our POJO variable name should be used in our HQL.

FROM Person p JOIN p.book
 b WHERE p.persionId=personid