# What is the correct Hibernate Query syntax for a join between two classes / tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have been at this for hours without success. For everything I try from other incidents logged here or examples elsewhere, the HQL syntax always seems to be wrong in my method:

```
 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try { 


        Query query = session.createQuery("select p from Person p join p.books where p.personId = :personId").setParameter("personId", personId);

        List<Person> persons = query.list();    
        Person person = persons.get(0);
        Hibernate.initialize(person.getBooks());
        return person;
    }        
    finally {
        session.close();            
    }
```

And every time Hibernate gives me a message like:

> Your page request has caused a SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement error:

My two Java classes are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

// Attributes.    
@Id
@Column(name="PERSON_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)    
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer personId;

@Column(name="NAME", nullable=false, length=50)      
private String name;

@Column(name="ADDRESS", nullable=false, length=100)
private String address;

@Column(name="TELEPHONE", nullable=false, length=10)
private String telephone;

@Column(name="EMAIL", nullable=false, length=50)
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)     
private List<Book> books;
```

And:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book implements Serializable {

// Attributes.
@Id
@Column(name="BOOK_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer bookId;

@Column(name="AUTHOR", nullable=false, length=50)
private String author;

@Column(name="TITLE", nullable=false, length=50)
private String title;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION", nullable=false, length=500)
private String description;

@Column(name="ONLOAN", nullable=false, length=5)
private String onLoan;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="person_Id")    
private Person person;
```

Can someone please tell me where I am wrong?

Hibernate returns this if is of any use:

```
select person0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON_I1_1_0_, book2_.BOOK_ID as BOOK_ID1_0_1_, person0_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS2_1_0_, person0_.EMAIL as EMAIL3_1_0_, person0_.NAME as NAME4_1_0_, person0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHON5_1_0_, book2_.AUTHOR as AUTHOR2_0_1_, book2_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_0_1_, book2_.ONLOAN as ONLOAN4_0_1_, book2_.person_Id as person_I6_0_1_, book2_.TITLE as TITLE5_0_1_, books1_.PERSON_PERSON_ID as PERSON_P1_1_0__, books1_.books_BOOK_ID as books_BO2_2_0__ from PERSON person0_ left outer join PERSON_BOOK books1_ on person0_.PERSON_ID=books1_.PERSON_PERSON_ID left outer join BOOK book2_ on books1_.books_BOOK_ID=book2_.BOOK_ID where person0_.PERSON_ID=?
```

Using a query as follows:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select from Person as p left join fetch p.books where p.personId = :personId").setParameter("personId", personId);
```

The stack trace is:

```
Your page request has caused a QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: from near line 1, column 8 [select from library.model.Person as p left join fetch p.books where p.personId = :personId] error:
```

> ```
>  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
> ```
>
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
>   library.dao.PersonDAOImpl.get(PersonDAOImpl.java:57)
>   library.service.PersonService.get(PersonService.java:32)
>   library.service.PersonService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7dacb914.invoke()
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
>   library.service.PersonService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b855c56c.get()
>   library.controller.PersonController.idValid(PersonController.java:112)
>   library.controller.PersonController.getLogin(PersonController.java:80)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: If you are just trying to get the Books within a Person, you dont need to use a JOIN Clause, just loading the Person object will fetch their related books lazily, or atleast thats how it works for me normally.

Comment: Unfortunately, any time I try that I get a message to do with the session having closed before the books can be retrieved from the database.

Comment: ahh thats because its being fetch lazily, so you need to change lazy fetch to eager fetch. Being lazily fetch means that it only loads them once you try and read their value.. but if you try and read the value after the session is closed then it cant do that (hence the exception).

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep LAZY fetching. So because I get errors about the session being closed, I'm trying to load the Books within the get Person method using Hibernate.initialize(person.getBooks());

Comment: Yep, just accessing their variables so they are loaded before the session is closed should do the trick.

Comment: But assuming my code is correct, it doesn't. It is vexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`JOIN FETCH`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins-forms) to eagerly load the linked collection:

```
FROM Person as p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.books WHERE p.personId = :personId
```

Comment: Gives: `Your page request has caused a SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement error:`

Comment: Strange. Any more details in the exception?

Comment: Not much, Hibernate query appended to question.

Comment: There's nothing between `SELECT` and `FROM` in your query. You can just remove the `SELECT`.

Comment: Causes `Your page request has caused a SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement error:`